# Present tense of the verb stuck

Tags: grammar, word-usage, verbs, tenses

I want to say "he stuck the wheel" or "the function stuck the browser" or "the function is stucking(sticking?) the browser".

But "stuck" is the past tense and the above examples happen now, what would be the right expression for this?

Comment: So what you mean is "he caused the wheel to stick" or "the function caused the browser to stick"? *Stick* doesn't work there; but *slow* or *stop* might: "He slowed the wheel; he stopped the wheel"; "the function stopped the browser". But we don't often use transitive verbs in this direct fashion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The present tense of the verb *stuck* is *stick*.

However, it is not idiomatic to say *he sticks the wheel*; the meaning is unclear.

Equally, functions do not *stick* the browser; they may *freeze* the browser or cause it to freeze/hang/crash.

However, the passive voice is frequently used to say things like:

> My browser is stuck

or

> The car is stuck in the mud.

or

> I am stuck

meaning that I cannot resolve a difficulty, or that I cannot get from where I am to where I want to go.

Answer (score -1):

"Stuck" in the examples above is used as an Adjective as opposed to the past simple or participle of "Stick"

Stuck in this case means the following ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stuck))

> unable to move, or set in a particular position, place, or way of thinking
>
> in a difficult situation, or unable to change or get away from a situation